# customize of autoref

Tags: hyperref

in this example, how can I customize `\autoref`. ie instead of printing `table 1`, it puts `Tab.1`
same question with `Figure = Fig.` and `equation = Eq.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf,sc,small},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

change the writing of \autoref{tab} to Tab.1

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
table & Tab. \\
\hline
figure & Fig. \\
\hline
equation & Eq. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Exemple d'environnement table}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since your question is about the `\autoref` command provided by the `hyperref` package, I've removed the `cleveref` tag, added the `hyperref` tag, and removed the instruction `\usepackage{cleveref}`. If, however, the question is really meant to be about the `cleveref` package and its command `\cref`, please indicate that that's the case.

Answer (score 10):

Voila:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf,sc,small},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.} % PS

change the writing of \autoref{tab} to Tab.1

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
table & Tab. \\
\hline
figure & Fig. \\
\hline
equation & Eq. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Exemple d'environnement table}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

One should change not the meaning of `\somethingname` but `\somethingautorefname`. In this case it is `\tableautorefname`.

[image]

Comment: exactly what I want .. thank you very much ...

Comment: Note: crucial is to put the `renewcommand ...` statement after \begin{document} -- I was trying in the preamble and didn't work.

Comment: nice catch @juanmirocks ! How did you discover it? Anyone can shed any insight as to why this only works after `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: Would you know what is the equivalent of `\tableauautorefname` for `enumerate`? RE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564957/customize-the-name-of-autoref-for-a-list-item cc @simo @juanmirocks @cipriantomoiaga