# customize appearance of cross-references to 'subfigure' objects

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption, autoref

In regard to these questions

> [customize of autoref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142687/customize-of-autoref)
>   and
>   [\autoref does not expand abbreviation automatically at beginning of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153471/autoref-does-not-expand-abbreviation-automatically-at-beginning-of-line)

I would like to know, how I can customize the pasting of additional brackets.

Example:
Instead of showing [image], Latex should display [image] when I use `\autoref`.

Minimal coding example:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% optional T1 font encoding
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]

    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures1}
        \caption{Nice image1}
        \label{fig:NiceImage1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures2}
        \caption{Nice image 2}
        \label{fig:NiceImage2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Two images}

    \label{fig:NiceImage}

\end{figure}


\autoref{fig:NiceImage1}
% Latex should display and reference to Figure 1(a)


\end{document}
```

I am sorry, if this is a duplicate of an already answered question!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working code example (compilable) to help us help you.

Comment: I provided a minimal working code example!

Comment: Well, it is not compilable, the preamble is missing (documentclass, packages, setup).

Comment: is it now alright?

Comment: Off-topic for the question at hand, but highly relevant nevertheless: `cleveref` should be loaded *after*, not before, `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `subcaption` documentation, page 9:

> If you want parentheses around the sub-figure part of the reference,
>   so they will look like ‘1(a)’, you may get them this way:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
> \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
> ```

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% optional T1 font encoding
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp!]

    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Nice image1}
        \label{fig:NiceImage1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Nice image 2}
        \label{fig:NiceImage2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Two images}

    \label{fig:NiceImage}

\end{figure}


\autoref{fig:NiceImage1}
% Latex should display and re


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you samcarter!!! Now, everything is working nicely!!!